# how to integrate mobile advertising like mopub or nmobi in ionic 3

Tags: cordova, typescript, ads, ionic3, mopub

i would like to know how to use **mopub** or other mobile advertising with new ionic 3 especially after update from **javascript** to **Typescript**
someone know the method for using ads with typescript in ionic 3 ??

Answer (score 0):

You can do that either using *AdMob Free* or *AdMob Pro*(Paid version) **native plugins**.

[**AdMob Free**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/admob-free/)

[**AdMob Pro(Paid version)**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/admob-pro/)

Here is a nice Video about [**AdMob Free**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wXSAtSc0go) usage.

Nice article about it: [**Adding AdMob to Ionic framework application**](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/codeproject/adding-admob-to-ionic-framework-application-step-by-step/)